# KnowRob development repository

Tags: ros, knowrobtutorials, knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Want to Know What is KnowRob development repository ?!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48482/knowrob-development-repository./) by [Amal](https://answers.ros.org/users/3346/amal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2012-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The development of some new functionality is done in an internal repository of the IAS group. Once the code has reached a certain level of maturity, it is synchronized with the public repositories. Since the code in the development repository is not as stable as that in the public one, it is recommended to use the public code repository at http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest (as described at http://www.ros.org/wiki/knowrob)

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2012-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3